# How to reload paren page after iframe content window closed in print preview using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am loading pdf in iframe and print this iframe using
    iframe id using jquery as below

```
$('#print_payslip_pdf_frame_print_div1')
        .load(function () {
             this.contentWindow.print();
})
.attr('src', "file location");
```

Now I want to reload a page after iframe print window close.
   beforeunload,unload events did not call when close print preview of this. 
   how to do this ??

Comment: How do you close the window?

Comment: by using cancel or save buttons in print preview

Comment: Can you put in the HTML of the buttons you are clicking to close the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you load a PDF into an iFrame you can no longer control it with JavaScript. To overcome this limitation you need to use a JavaScript PDF renderer in your iFrame.

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/